# SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Failed to connect to server on Hostinger

Tags: smtp, phpmailer, laravel-10

Hello so my site is already on production and I used shared hosting from hostinger but whenever I create an account it always give me SMTP Error but I can create an account. only the emailing is not working supposed to be the system will sent an account credentials please help this is my first time working on smtp if anyone could point out what I'm missing or mistakes thanks

this is the .env file

```
EMAIL_HOST = testingweb.com
EMAIL_USERNAME = no-reply-web@testingweb.com
EMAIL_PASSWORD = Te$ting123
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_ENCRYPTION = TLS
EMAIL_FROM_NAME = CCS
EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS = no-reply-web@testing.com
```

The Helper file

```
    <?php
    //PHP Mailer
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    
        //PHP Mailer Function
        if(!function_exists('sendMail')){
            function sendMail($mailConfig){
                require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
                require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
                require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
        
                $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
                $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
                $mail->isSMTP();
                $mail->Host = env('EMAIL_HOST');
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                $mail->Username = env('EMAIL_USERNAME');
                $mail->Password = env('EMAIL_PASSWORD');
                $mail->SMTPSecure = env('EMAIL_ENCRYPTION');
                $mail->Port = env('EMAIL_PORT');
                $mail- 
 >setFrom($mailConfig['mail_from_email'],$mailConfig['mail_from_name']);
                $mail->addAddress($mailConfig['mail_recipient_email'],$mailConfig['mail_recipient_name']);
                $mail->isHTML(true);
                $mail->Subject = $mailConfig['mail_subject'];
                $mail->Body = $mailConfig['mail_body'];
        
                if($mail->send()){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

sending Function email

if($saved){

```
                        $mail_body = view('new-user-email-message-form', $data)->render();
    
                        $mailConfig = array(
                            'mail_from_email'=> env('EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'),
                            'mail_from_name'=> env('EMAIL_FROM_NAME'),
                            'mail_recipient_email'=> $user_email,
                            'mail_recipient_name'=> $user_name,
                            'mail_subject'=> 'Account Details',
                            'mail_body'=> $mail_body
                           
                
                        );
                
                        //send email and password to the user email address
                        sendMail($mailConfig);
```

appreciate any help thanks

Comment: By the looks of the error message, `testingweb.com` is not running an SMTP server, or Hostinger is explicitly blocking access to it.

Comment: It always helps to [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host).